# How to make PySpark process an hdfs file

Tags: python, ubuntu, hadoop, pyspark, hdfs

I have recently setup a **single node** Hadoop cluster on **Ubuntu** 18-LTS and have also installed **pySpark** (along with anaconda). The installation(s) have been verified to be working. However, I can't get pySpark to process a file which is in hdfs.

```
hduser@master:~$ hdfs dfs -ls /user/local/hadoop_data/hdfs/hduser/
Found 1 items
-rw-r--r--   1 hduser supergroup    1979173 2018-08-07 23:01 /user/local/hadoop_data/hdfs/hduser/test.data
```

In the python code I reference the hdfs file as :

```
lines = sc.textFile("hdfs:///user/local/hadoop_data/hdfs/hduser/test.data")
```

The script is:

```
    hduser@master:~$ cat count_ratings.py
    from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
    import collections

    conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("RatingsHistogram")
    sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

    lines = sc.textFile("hdfs:///user/local/hadoop_data/hdfs/hduser/test.data")
    ratings = lines.map(lambda x: x.split()[2])
    result = ratings.countByValue()
    ... ...
```

I execute the script as :

```
hduser@master:~$ spark-submit count_ratings.py
```

Unfortunately, I get the error :

```
2018-08-08 00:02:14 INFO  SparkContext:54 - Created broadcast 0 from textFile at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hduser/count_ratings.py", line 9, in <module>
    result = ratings.countByValue()
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1279, in countByValue
... ..
```

I am fairly certain that error lies in the syntax I am using to reference the file in hdfs, since the same script runs successfully when referencing a same  copy of the data on my local(home dir). Can anyone please indicate the syntax to reference hdfs files with pySpark ? Any help is appreciated..

Thanks..

Comment: what did you configure for hdfs? https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/85757/how-to-add-the-hadoop-and-yarn-configuration-file.html

Comment: First, `INFO` message is not an error... Second, that is a very odd HDFS path... `/user/local/hadoop_data/hdfs/hduser`... Why didn't you upload to `hdfs:///user/hduser/` directly? And have you tried the `pyspark` REPL?

Comment: The error I get is a connection refused error : `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hduser/count_ratings.py", line 10, in <module>
    result = ratings.countByValue()
  ...
: java.net.ConnectException: Call From master/XXX.XXX.X.X to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused` .Also when I try to check the same it gives the same error :- `$ telnet localhost
Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused`